# onCreateLoader is blocking the UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, loader

I want to try Loaders. But when i call initLoader() like it's done in the documentation, the UI-Thread is getting blocked with the code from onCreateLoader. Isn't that the whole point of Loaders?
Why is that, and what should i do to prevent the UI-Thread from beeing blocked here?
I am using debugging in Android Studio on the Nexus 5.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_content_provider_test);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle args) {
    //Do nothing 100000000 times
    for(int i=0; i< 100000000; i++)
        ;
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    //nothing to display
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    //nothing to reset
}
```

Comment: *Isn't that the whole point of Loaders?* - that is the point of loaders. However, those callback methods run on the thread where the `LoaderManager.Callbacks` was registered(the main thread in your case).

Comment: So you are telling me that i just have to call initLoader from a background thread? But why is every example using the UI-Thread? e.g. http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But when i call initLoader() like it's done in the documentation, the UI-Thread is getting blocked with the code from onCreateLoader.

As Luksprog notes, `onCreateLoader()` is called on the same thread that `initLoader()` is called on, and usually that is the main application thread. The job of `onCreateLoader()` to create the `Loader`, as you might have guessed by the name.

> Isn't that the whole point of Loaders?

The point of a `Loader` is to load data. The point of an `AsyncTaskLoader` is to load data asynchronously. You are welcome to create some other `Loader` that does not inherit from `AsyncTaskLoader`, in which case doing the loading asynchronously is *your* job.

> what should i do to prevent the UI-Thread from beeing blocked here?

Write a correct implementation of `onCreateLoader()`, one that creates a `Loader` instance and returns it, rather than looping 100000000 times and then returning `null`.

This is covered in [the documentation on the `Loader` framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#callback).

Comment: Does this mean that LoaderManager does not run in a thread of their own? Only Loaders doInBackground() run in a separate thread. The LoaderManger then must be using his own custom Handler object to receive messages on the UI thread once the loader thread finish loading the data. Then based on the message the Loader posted, LoaderManager would call the callbacks registered by the Activity Class.

Comment: @SumitTrehan: "Does this mean that LoaderManager does not run in a thread of their own?" -- correct, at least by my reading of [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java). "The LoaderManger then must be using his own custom Handler object" -- no. The `Loader` notifies the `LoaderManager` via an `OnLoadCompleteListener` that the loading work is complete.

Comment: onLoadComlete() method acts as the callback for the LoaderManager, which is further calling the onLoadFinished(). How come this function gets called by the UI thread, since the Loader must be calling the callback from the background thread?

Comment: @SumitTrehan: "since the Loader must be calling the callback from the background thread?" -- the `Loader` is not necessarily calling the callback from the background thread. In fact, the only concrete `Loader` in the Android SDK, `CursorLoader`, inherits from [`AsyncTaskLoader`, which calls `onLoadComplete()` from `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.java).

Comment: Ok.. So then AsyncTask internally must be using Handler object to post message to the UI thread about the completion of the task. In processing of which onPostExecute() would be called by the UI thread?

Comment: @SumitTrehan: Yes, [`AsyncTask` uses a `Handler`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java).

Comment: Can you look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134861/background-thread-state-when-activity-is-stopped-or-destroyed