# Background thread state when activity is stopped or destroyed

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Lets us say, we start some threads from the main UI thread. Now suppose the activity gets stopped or destroyed.

```
onClick () { /* Activity onClickListener for some button */

new Thread (new MyThread (new Handler ())).start ();
}


private class MyThread implements Runnable  {

    Handler mUIHandler;

    MyThread (Handler h) {
    mUIHandler = h;
    }

    public void run () {

     /* Long operation */

     /* Post status update to UI */
     Message msg  = mUIHandler.obtainMessage ();
     msg.obj = String.valueOf (statusCode);
     mUIHandler.sendMessage (msg);

    }
```

1) What would happen to those threads ?

2) From those threads, suppose I would br posting some messages to the UI thread using the UI thread Handler object, What would happen to those UI updates then?

Comment: If parent process is stop or destroyed then Threads are also killed by system forcefully.

Comment: Nothing really happens to them and they continue to run until they finish (assuming it's the activity that was destroyed and not the actual process). With regards to posting messages to UI, you need to be very careful and make sure you are posting the messages if your code is still attached to an activiy. Easiest (yet not the absolute safest) way is to do a simple check of `if getActivity() == null` in a fragment or `if isDestroyed()` in the activity to make sure it's still attached and alive.